# MultiSelectListPreference onSharedPreferenceChanged not called after first time

Tags: android, settings, sharedpreferences

I have a MultiSelectListPreference in my preferences file:

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="TYPES" >
    <MultiSelectListPreference
        android:defaultValue="@array/empty_array"
        android:entries="@array/types"
        android:entryValues="@array/typeValues"
        android:key="types"
        android:title="Types" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

Then in code:

```
public class PublicPreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    PublicPreferenceFragment preference = new PublicPreferenceFragment();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, preference).commit();
    }

   public class PublicPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.publicpreferences);

            for (int i = 0; i < getPreferenceScreen().getPreferenceCount(); i++) {
                initSummary(getPreferenceScreen().getPreference(i));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Set up a listener whenever a key changes
        preference.getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        preference.getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        // do something
        // this does not get called all the time for MultiSelectListPreference
    }
}
```

I have searched around and it seems others have had this problem but no workarounds have been provided.

I have seen a comment here that there may have been a bug in the SDK up to API 18, but cannot confirm that anywhere, and again no workaround. [Android MultiSelectListPreference uncheck does not fire SharedPreferenceChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077568/android-multiselectlistpreference-uncheck-does-not-fire-sharedpreferencechanged)

So is this a bug?  Is there a workaround?

Seems like a pretty big bug, so I feel like I am doing something wrong to cause this.

Answer (score 0):

I am dealing with the same issue. From SDK 18 all thing seems to work fine but in rest, I have same issue like you.

I found a solution that seems to work for me:

```
MultiSelectListPreference multiSelectListPref = (MultiSelectListPreference) findPreference("pref_name");
if (multiSelectListPref != null) {
    multiSelectListPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            MultiSelectListPreference mpreference = (MultiSelectListPreference) preference;
            mpreference.setSummary(newValue.toString());
            mpreference.setValues((Set<String>) newValue);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

maybe it is useful for your cases too

Comment: This does not work. correct solution is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/22804325/398348